# How do I fix "base64: invalid input" error in github workflow publish (gpg)?

Tags: github, github-actions, gnupg

I'm running a github workflow I've used many times in the past to publish code to nexus.  It is failing now.  I haven't used it in a while, so it's possible my original key expired...been >3 yrs since I created it and I can't remember if I set it to expire or not.

I generated a new rsa key with gpg and default length (about 3K I think), published it to keyserver.ubuntu.com, and pasted it into my secret variable PGP_SECRET in my project's github repo, which my gpg command uses.

I run my workflow with the gpg command in it, and get this error:

```
Running ci-release.
  branch=refs/tags/v1.2.2
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
java.lang.RuntimeException: base64: invalid input
...
[error] base64: invalid input
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

What is this error, and how can I fix it?  Does this mean my RSA key is bad/unrecognized by github?

(I'll add that I can successfully encrypt/decript with my key locally using gpg.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the missing piece--need to convert to base64.

Steps:

```
1. gpg --full-generate-key   (answer all promopts--remember passphrase)
    -> Choose RSA, default length
2. gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys <key_id>   (publish key to the world)
3. gpg --armor --export-secret-keys <key_id> | base64
4. cut/paste this ascii block into wherever it will be use, e.g. github secret var
```